# Indexed search displaying results in another page

Tags: search, typo3

I want to have a search box on top of the header, but when I submit keywords, I dont want the results to appear on the header, but on the body.

To do this, I thought id have the plugin once in the header and another in the body in a special "Search" page, where I could hide the from in the header when the user was using this page. But I dont know how to do, so that when a search is done, to jump to this other page. (Its sort of like when tt_news has a single pid to go from LIST to SINGLE)

How can I do it to do this jump? Or maybe is there an easier way to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On common pages you need to construct "pure html" in the header part with the search form where its action is link to the another page - displaying search results. It uses `typolink` for generating proper form's action.

On the page with search results you don't need to hide the search form, instead you can use TypoScript to fill the search field with value entered on the common page.

There is `ready-to-use` sample of TypoScript for such scenario placed in `Introduction Package`, I don't use it so sorry, but I won't paste it here. Anyway you can install it locally and dig for nice snippets and techniques.

Comment: Thanks, Ill think Ill do that.